# Cannot import pyqgis into PythonWin

Tags: pyqgis, pythonwin, importerror

I'm new to pyqgis so I may be headed in the wrong direction on this. I imported qgis on python consolde in qgis, no problem. However when I try to do this in PythonWin, I get an error saying the module does not exist. I tried os.listdir for all folders where QGIS is installed and can't find the module anywhere. Need to write a stand alone script in a batch process so I can't use the QGIS python console. Is there something I'm missing?

Here is import from QGIS console:

```
    import qgis
    help(qgis)
    Help on package qgis:

    NAME
        qgis

    FILE
        c:\progra~2\qgis2~1.14\apps\qgis-ltr\python\qgis\__init__.py

    DESCRIPTION...
```

and here is the error from PythonWin:

```
import qgis
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named qgis
```

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed?  For me using Pycharm on Linux (works on Windows too) I need to have Python 2.7 as the interpreter, rather than my python version 3+

Comment: @nmtoken I ran os.listdir() in program files where both ArcGIS and QGIS are installed. Python 2.7 was initially installed with ArcMap and I don't see another version anywhere else in program files.

Comment: @geoJshaun did you find the answer? this is where I'm stuck for days! Best wishes.

Comment: @AfshinSalehi No, I never did unfortunately